# Map a specific photocurrent range from photodiode to ADC range 0 V .. 3.3 V

Tags: adc, current-measurement, dac, photodiode

### Problem

Measure tiny current fluctuations in photo-diode. Lets say that photo-diode outputs \$2300\text{ nA} \pm 100\text{ nA}\$. Then that needs to be mapped to ADC. So \$2200\text{ nA} .. 2400\text{ nA} \rightarrow 0\text{ V} .. 3.3\text{ V}\$.

### Suggested circuit

This could potentially map photo-current \$2200\text{ nA} .. 2400\text{ nA} \rightarrow 0\text{ V} .. 3.3\text{ V}\$. The gain is not perfect.

[Falstad simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEBmAHAJmgdgGzoRmACzICcpkORIW1SJICApgLRhgBQA7iOlulF78QVKBwBO4HJEF8BMmWHhwOAS3Bh5ghSOjl9Bw6laoOAeSEDRckKkViAhiCKiiqRrmfv3YJGyRKygrQ6MguyMhgZMhUBHbyIWE4COxgqKjICEnoOOBB3FI6YNJeYgDmgpruikTUCmoaAm6CzcFBoQU6Mq0F7E0%20mtq9g83F3dUcTmMi1DaiPn6%20eUEgLDDtMeS4yHChOFtIivmSLtRsuQie55X5PJe51-elkAWnq8XOosjyEp-U3ygEAIAUcVCdRF8gTMbmC-tC3lUYfAOAAlQHA4FQrrOYLodAQNawSBaGAIcweXLNKjjcBiHg0xToCY8aZ2QrgJl0uGI6aIl70jk%20Ep8jgAI1WAJYAOIuVQpDEAA9eLksFg8rLulIQAAFAAWAHsAC76gAmqlNTA4SoiAhY7mQtFW9C1ZgAZq6AM5MQ1WxgMR38GSq5wugCuhoADuGADoe42xgCCABEAMKxyAAN1j8Y9yGgyAzBUyVlmwlELzQvEEbCJQTrcDArDVYFr9aCjZYapTofE4iYADsfZW0toQlB8yAAGr6gA2hocZUtQA)

[image]

- The `offset` could be controlled by a voltage divider or a DAC.
- Potentiometers could be added to calibrate.
- The op-amps will be supplied by ground and 5 V.
- I don't know if this is practical yet, it seems to work in theory.

### Question

1. Is there a alternative circuit that could be proven to be better than suggested circuit?
2. Any problem in suggested circuit? is it practical? Any fact based improvements?
3. Adding a voltage controlled offset and voltage controlled gain would make it possible to calibrate from MCU. A voltage controlled offset could just be connecting `Offset` to a DAC. But how would a voltage controlled gain be implemented?

Comment: There's always a better solution and asking for improvements is asking for opinions and, asking for opinions is a reason to close down questions: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.*

Comment: Good catch. I improved my question to avoid opinions.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet showing the typical characteristics of the photodiode? I would search for manufacturer datasheets with sample I-V converters in sample applications.

Comment: I don't have a specific photodiode in mind. I want to have the option to test any photodiode and be able to calibrate or just change resistor value depending on photodiode. Most datasheets  I-V converters examples I have seen is the same and uses one op-amp that measures the entire range.

Comment: Given the relatively high photocurrent you are probably going to need to reverse bias the photodiode to avoid saturation. Adjusting the offsets is also going to be annoying unless your source is very stable and your optical alignment doesn't change because small fluctuations will push output to the rails. If you can AC couple that will make things a lot easier.

Comment: Yes I have the same thought adjusting offset might not be practical. I have read that Photoconductive mode is faster and Photovoltaic mode is less noise. I don't need speed I need little noise but I will probably try both. The source and optical alignment will be constant. The experiment I'm trying to do is to check how reflectivity of substance changes over time. And I already know that it will vary in nA by using precision instruments. It will not fly of the rails.

Answer (score 0):

> Any problem in suggested circuit?

One problem is that the offset is very sensitive to change.

> Is there a alternative circuit?

Yes there is. Use negative offset on the first op-amp. But the disadvantage is that it requires a extra battery or power source for below ground voltage i.e. negative voltage. [Falstad simulation alternative solution with negative offset](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEBmAHAJmgdgGzoRmACzICcpkORIW1SJICApgLRhgBQA7iOluiDY5e-EFSgcATuByRBYYXwFCo4eHA4BLGapalhcuW1jrTpsKywcA8iIHilIVHIiRuMowo8giqCQHNBfV4iI2D8AwltL18g4VjDE3h0ZHc9SPSfPzceGL8vQ3c87wSpH3EVBFx5SLBTdyrhSurSniIKmPFkATdbRqyxUIHXNODYzPQhnLiQuVjJwoAPQSw-FmQIZXQ-ai8ABQALAHsAFyOAE00Lpg5lhAZaGnQ5LCwfHWsAVxOAB2%20AHQAzmcgQBBAAiAGEgZAAG5AkGA5DQZCwspoagqdqYgpqDShUjeByicSuaCRGCQFJ1MxmAToDgE8rUWL9WJkimwam0um8dzPPzhSB%20BYSHgIMACZyMSWzCQAJRlAi8Ep6qjmciQhig0AQHEVApQ9OFOm1Qy16t1HECGJqKFQuwp-JJLPE4mmhtFqrlbiZ7Nk4CIjpcOs5VI2PNM9P1IGCksFwnYao1jHVOr1sNjidIAnCU1UQ2RyDTMD1PDzck9UzKxGo0ti0pc8DKDaM3Sc2ppGjaIqGFbFA3r%20SDElste847A1RGivWUrbytlZsr0Cn2UtZcDdZcI4UhVyI%20le47A-ZLV7S0EqGLYGQwmQuzI7y81gAZq-AUwTkDX5IjgBbIFwVBSEODQXgQAAMVceQkkjeALBYN4wDg%20DIEQt42BASFPkkSQmAAOxOMC-GQN5oLTIt5BAAA1I4ABsTgAQ38G4gA)
[image: Falstad simulation alternative solution with negative offset]